# Joomla MVC component with languages from database

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, multilingual

How do I create a multi-language Joomla MVC component with built-in language function of joomla. 
This translation must be inserted into database and then output to the frontend according to the language not the pre-defined `.ini` translation.

P/s: I could build a component in joomla already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a language column on your database tables and then you can do on the front in your model where you fetch the items

```
if (JLanguageMultilang::isEnabled())
{
    $query->where('a.language in (' . $db->quote(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag()) . ',' . $db->quote('*') . ')');
}
```

The forms need to have a language field as well

```
<field name="language" type="contentlanguage"
    label="JFIELD_LANGUAGE_LABEL" description="JFIELD_LANGUAGE_DESC"
    class="inputbox">
    <option value="*">JALL</option>
</field>
```

The best is when you have a look how the com_content component did it.